# Python: Indent print output from class

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I indent the print output on the command line from a class that is called? I can't edit the class file to add tabs to each print().

So I would call the imported class in mypythonthing.py:

```
print('Calling class')
MyClass()
```

All the print output would then be indented, or have something prepended to it.

e.g.

```
$ python mypythonthing.py
$ Running your python script...
$ Calling class
$    > The print output from MyClass is indented
$    > Exiting MyClass
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patch the built-in `print` function to prefix each line with your indentation.

```
import builtins

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    builtins.print("    > ", *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Does this persist across imported scripts?

Comment: No. However, as long as your imported script doesn't call `print` immediately upon import, you can patch the module's global `print` with `import foo; foo.print = print`. There is probably a way to actually patch `builtins.print` (using `__builtins__.print` to use the *real* `print` function), but my attempts resulted in infinite recursion. Maybe someone else can figure out the right incantation.

Comment: @chepner I take it this would indent all output though? So in my example `print('Calling class')` would have the custom indentation too?

Comment: You would have to patch *after* the first `print`. If that and `MyClass` are in the module you are importing, you're out of luck. Or rather, please edit your question to provide a small example of such a module you want to import, along with an example of how you would import it.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, this works perfectly. As a sidenote for others I had to add `@staticmethod` above the `def`, otherwise I was getting some object info from the class printing along with the output.

Answer (score 3):

If you can put the code that should be indented inside (one or more) functions, *then* you can use a decorator to wrap these functions.

Then any invocation of `print` inside these function will be indented.
Also, you will only need to declare this function in your main script, and not anywhere else.

Example -

```
import builtins
import another # for demo purposes only

# This will override the default `print` function.
# Invoking it as a decorator will automatically perform
# initialisation and cleanup. There is also never a need
# to modify this.

def indent(f):
    def closure():
        old = builtins.print
        builtins.print = lambda x, *args, **kwargs:  old("\t>", x, *args, **kwargs)
        f()
        builtins.print = old
    return closure

some_number = "100"

# Example function, note decorator usage.
# This function may **not** take any parameters!
# It may however, use any variables declared before it.

@indent
def indentedStuffGoesHere():
    print("Inside `indentedStuffGoesHere`")
    print(some_number)
    another.Foo().bar()
    another.stuff()


print("entering special block")
indentedStuffGoesHere()
print("done")
```

---

another.py

```
def stuff():
    print("TESTING stuff")

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print("HELLO FROM FOO")
```

---

Output:

```
entering special block
    > Inside `indentedStuffGoesHere`
    > 100
    > HELLO FROM FOO
    > TESTING stuff
done
```

Comment: @Rishnav This looks like a good solution, however I kept getting an error message when I tried it: `TypeError: closure() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given`

Comment: Please check it once more :)

Comment: @Rishnav Not exactly, I copied parts into the class that was calling `MyClass`. It's most likely something I've not done right there. I was able to get @chepner's answer to work - which does the trick for my case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

i think what you might be looking for is textwrap:
[textwrap docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html)
so as an example:

```
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=preferredWidth, subsequent_indent='\t')
message = "asdf" * 50
print wrapper.fill(message)
```

Comment: I did look into this, but couldn't get it working properly with the class output.